# Heroku /app/bin directory is missing

Tags: python, django, heroku

Committed a small code change to my django app and deployed to heroku. The app now throws H10 (app crashed) errors on every response. When I checked the logs, I saw..

```
[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[web.1]:   File "nightlife2/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
[web.1]:     from django.core.management import execute_manager
[web.1]: ImportError: No module named django.core.management
[web.1]: bash: bin/gunicorn_django: No such file or directory
```

..which I know means that django isn't on the pythonpath. I looked at the PATH on the heroku config which says `bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. But while doing a `heroku run bash`, I noticed that the entire `bin` directory is now gone. Other apps of mine deployed on heroku can still be pushed to and still have the `bin` directory on there (I believe newer apps no longer have the bin directory and it's now in .heroku/venv/bin. Not 100% sure on the details there)

Has anyone ever encountered this? I can change the PATH to `.heroku/venv/bin` but then I get an error about sql and I don't know if this is closer or farther away from the root problem. ANYTHING would be greatly appreciated as this is the production server and is currently hosed.

EDIT: The error when changing the path is: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named _sqlite3`
. The database is postgress so I'm not sure where this is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was a combination of things. I'll document here and hopefully saves someone the headache I just experienced.

Our database had just been updated to the new Heroku Postgres dev plan. (Unsure if this is related or not). This was the first push of code since the database had been updated.

A while back I remember hearing about settings injections being deprecated. Being naive, we did nothing about it and never saw any changes so never followed up about it. They decided to take effect today and broke the linking to our postgres database. I'm still unsure as to why the `bin` directory is now gone, but it appears that the app is now using the new `.heroku/venv/bin`. To fix all of this, I had to change the settings.py to use the new postgres declaration for the database. I was correct in my OP that the PATH variable in the `heroku config` needed to be updated to point to the `.heroku/venv/bin` directory. I then had to update the Procfile because it was complaining about `bin/gunicorn_django` not being found. Once everything was updated, pushing the code solved the issue